# GitLab - OpenAPI yaml file is too big

Tags: gitlab, swagger, openapi

We have a big OpenAPI file, and how can I view it online?

[image]

I hope to view that like below:

[image]

ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/openapi/openapi_interactive.html

Comment: Did you try clicking the `load it anyway` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GitLab documentation on its [OpenAPI viewer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#openapi-viewer) (emphasis mine):

> **The filename must include `openapi` or `swagger`** and the extension must be `yaml`, `yml`, or `json`.

Your file name `framework.yml` does not match the expected pattern.